# Kotlin how to Map JSONArray to Type (Stream)

Tags: kotlin, functional-programming, stream

I'm trying to map my `JSONArray` to a `Array<String?>`.

I'm doing it like this:

```
fun getTextResponse(responseJson: JSONObject): Array<String?>{
        val resultData = responseJson.getJSONArray("data")
                .getJSONObject(0)
                .getJSONArray("result")

        return resultData.map{ it.getString("label") }.toTypedArray()
}
```

But `it` is not typed as a `JSONObject`, is there any way I can force type it to `JSONObject` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that `resultData` has a type of `JSONArray`, which is a JSON utility class that doesn't overrides Kotlin/Java `Array` interface and thus doesn't have a `map` function.

You have to retrieve each string by index and generate new array like this:

```
fun getTextResponse(responseJson: JSONObject): Array<String?> {
    val resultData = responseJson.getJSONArray("data")
            .getJSONObject(0)
            .getJSONArray("result")
    return Array<String?>(resultData.length()) { i -> resultData.getString(i) }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

What [jackqack](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3653330/jackqack) proposed in his [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54137854/1788806) is what you should do, I just want to add that since you want to return an `Array<String?>` you should also map exceptions to null. This will make your code more robust. The generic type argument can be inferred too, so it can be omitted.

```
fun getTextResponse(responseJson: JSONObject): Array<String?> {
    val resultData = responseJson.getJSONArray("data")
            .getJSONObject(0)
            .getJSONArray("result")

    return Array(resultData.length()) { i ->

        try {
            resultData.getString(i)
        } catch (e: JSONException){
            null
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that your `resutData` does not have a `map` function! See https://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONArray.

What you can do instead is iterate over the JSONArray and add every entry to your new Array, like this:

```
fun getTextResponse(responseJson: JSONObject): Array<String?>{
    val resultData = responseJson.getJSONArray("data")
            .getJSONObject(0)
            .getJSONArray("result")

    val arrayList = ArrayList<String>()
    for (i in 0..resultData.length()) {
        arrayList.add(resultData[i].toString())
    }

    return arrayList.toArray(arrayOfNulls<String>(arrayList.size))
}
```