# I want to declare an Array of type String that returns for me : Array<String>? not Array<String?>

Tags: android, kotlin

I am creating an AsyncTaskLoader
I override in my Main Activity this function:

```
override fun loadInBackground(): Array<String>? {
return OpenWeatherJsonUtils.getSimpleWeatherStringsFromJson(this@MainActivity, jsonWeatherResponse)
}
```

Note that this function cannot accept any type except: Array<String>?

and in my OpenWeatherJsonUtils.getSimpleWeatherStringsFromJson function, I have this code:

```
@Throws(JSONException::class)
fun getSimpleWeatherStringsFromJson(context: Context, forecastJsonStr: String): Array<String>? {

var parsedWeatherData: Array<String>?

val weatherArray = forecastJson.getJSONArray(OWM_LIST)

parsedWeatherData = arrayOfNulls<String>(weatherArray.length())

for (int i = 0; i < weatherArray.length(); i++) {
parsedWeatherData[i] = "$date - $description - $highAndLow"
        }

        return parsedWeatherData
}
```

The error is that the parsedWeatherData value required Array<String>? , and the arrayOfNulls function return Array<String?>

what I must add or use to return Array<String>? value that the loadInBackground() fun requires and as I mentioned above I cant change the type of loadInBackground() to other than Array<String>?

Note that I have a recycler view that display a weather data from JSON file from Internet and I try to add toTypedArray() and map{} to the arrayOfNulls but it does not work

Any help please
Thanks for attention.

Comment: why using arraOfNulls then?

Comment: any suggestion to use other than that?

Comment: weatherArray.map ?

Comment: @Blackbelt [JSONArray in android does not extends Collection](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54137854/11377112), so `for` loops and `map` are not allowed, and so factory function should be the right choice (and also because map creates list rather than array, so would need to copy the list into array by `toTypedArray`).

Answer (score 1):

Instead of creating Array of nulls, since you already have the data you can directly initialize the Array:

```kotlin
@Throws(JSONException::class)
fun getSimpleWeatherStringsFromJson(context: Context, forecastJsonStr: String): Array<String> {
    val weatherArray = forecastJson.getJSONArray(OWM_LIST)

    val parsedWeatherData = Array(weatherArray.length()) {
        with(weatherArray.getJSONObject(it)) {
            "${get("date")} - ${get("description")} - ${get("highAndLow")}"
        }
    }
    return parsedWeatherData
}
```